# Javamail don't send emails with attachments

Tags: tomcat, gmail, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I have an email session in Tomcat6:

```
<Resource name="email" scope="Shareable" type="javax.mail.Session" mail.debug="true" mail.smtp.user="XXXX@gmail.com" mail.smtp.password="XXXX" mail.smtp.host="smtp.gmail.com" mail.smtp.port="465" mail.smtp.auth="true" mail.smtp.socketFactory.port="465" mail.smtp.socketFactory.class="javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory" />
```

I send emails perfectly with this code:

```
javax.mail.Session sesion = getEmailSession();
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("XXXX@gmail.com"));
msg.setRecipients(new InternetAddress("XXXX@gmail.com"));
msg.setSubject(MimeUtility.encodeText("About","iso-8859-1","Q"));

Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();

MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
MimeBodyPart mbp2 = new MimeBodyPart();

mbp1.setText("Text","ISO-8859-15");

FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource("/opt/tmp/file.txt");           
mbp2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
mbp2.setFileName(fds.getName());

mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);
mp.addBodyPart(mbp2);

msg.setContent(mp);      
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
Transport.send(msg);
```

I works fine in all servers I have tried it (Windows and Linux), but in one server it doesn't work. The connection is closed abruptly.

I have debugged the javamail communication and I have:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.5
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP w67sm3313556wmw.17 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465

EHLO XXXX
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [88.2.96.135]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<XXXX@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK w67sm3313556wmw.17 - gsmtp
RCPT TO:<XXX@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 OK w67sm3313556wmw.17 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   XXX@gmail.com
DATA
354  Go ahead w67sm3313556wmw.17 - gsmtp
Date: Wed, 2 Dec 2015 14:49:44 +0100 (CET)
From: XXX@gmail.com
To: XXX@gmail.com
Message-ID: <17032702.26.1449064184719.JavaMail.root@Sage-Portal>
Subject: About
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_25_13365288.1449064184718"

------=_Part_25_13365288.1449064184718
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Text
------=_Part_25_13365288.1449064184718
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=file.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.txt

JAVAMAIL 1.4.5
------=_Part_25_13365288.1449064184718--
.
DEBUG SMTP: EOF: [EOF]
DEBUG SMTP: got response code -1, with response: [EOF]
RSET
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending
javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2163)
```

In this server sometimes the email with attachment is send, but normally not. If email has not attachments it always is send. In other servers the emails are always send.

what can be the problem: Tomcat6, Gmail, Javamail, the server...

Comment: Are all the Tomcat servers using the same SMTP server?  Is the server that fails a Windows server?  Is it running anti-virus or firewall software that might be interfering with the communication?

Comment: There are distincts smtp servers, but are there others with the same smtp server (gmail) that works fine. The server that fails is Linux. There is not anti-virus. The firewall is running and has a rule that lets this comunication...

Comment: Based on the failure, I think an anti-virus program is the most likely culprit, have you checked that?  If that's not it, provide more details of the machine running Tomcat and the SMTP server it's talking to.  Do other servers talk to that SMTP server successfully, using the same account?  Can the server that fails talk to a different SMTP server successfully?